# ¿Como solucionar promedio dentro del for ?Java Ciclo For

Tags: java, bucle-for

---

1. Se pide desarrollar el algoritmo para administrar las notas de los alumnos de programación básica I.

Se sabe que la cantidad de alumnos es 10.

Se debe poder ingresar:

a. Dni del alumno
b. Carrera (w – Tecnicatura en Desarrollo de Aplicaciones Web;  – Tecnicatura en Desarrollo de
Aplicaciones móviles)
c. Nota Primer Parcial
d. Nota Segundo Parcial
e. Nota Trabajo Practico

Se debe calcular:

a. Nota promedio de cada alumno
b. Cantidad de alumnos de la Tecnicatura en Desarrollo de Aplicaciones Web
c. Cantidad de alumnos de la Tecnicatura en Desarrollo de Aplicaciones móviles
d. Promedio notas Web
e. Promedio notas mobile

*No se como hacer el promedio de notas Web y Mobile.Ya que en la forma que lo hice me da cualquier resultado.

```
int alumnos = 10;
    int dni = 0;
    String carrera = " ";
    int parcial1W=0;
    int parcial1M=0;
    int parcial2W=0;
    int parcial2M=0;
    int notaTPW =0;
    int notaTPM =0;
    int promedioW = 0;
    int promedioM = 0;
    int cantidadAlumMobile = 0;
    int cantidadAlumWeb=0;
    int promedioWeb=0;
    int sumaW =0;
    int sumaM=0;
    int sumatoriaPW = 0;
    int sumatoriaPM=0;
    int promedioNWeb =0;
    int promedioNMobile=0;

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);

    for (int i = 1; i < alumnos; i++) {


        System.out.println(i+".Ingrese DNI : ");
        dni = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println(i+".Ingrese Carrera : ");
        carrera = teclado.next();

        switch(carrera) {


        case "Web":

            System.out.println(i+".Ingrese nota del 1er parcial : ");
            parcial1W = teclado.nextInt();

            System.out.println(i+"Ingrese nota del 2do parcial : ");
            parcial2W = teclado.nextInt();

            System.out.println(i+"Ingrese nota del T.P : ");
            notaTPW = teclado.nextInt();

            sumaW = parcial1W + parcial2W + notaTPW ;
            promedioW = sumaW/3;

            System.out.println(i+".Promedio : "+promedioW);

            cantidadAlumWeb++;
            promedioW++;

            break;

        case "Mobile" :

            System.out.println(i+".Ingrese nota del 1er parcial : ");
            parcial1M = teclado.nextInt();

            System.out.println(i+"Ingrese nota del 2do parcial : ");
            parcial2M = teclado.nextInt();

            System.out.println(i+"Ingrese nota del T.P : ");
            notaTPM = teclado.nextInt();

            sumaM = parcial1M + parcial2M + notaTPM;
            promedioM = sumaM/3;

            System.out.println(i+".Promedio : "+promedioM);

            cantidadAlumMobile++;
            promedioM++;

            break;

            default :

                System.out.println("Error! Carrera Inexistente.");

                break;



        }

        sumatoriaPW+=promedioW;
        sumatoriaPM+=promedioM;

    }



    promedioNWeb = sumatoriaPW / cantidadAlumWeb;
    promedioNMobile = sumatoriaPM / cantidadAlumMobile;

    System.out.println("Promedio Notas WEB : "+promedioNWeb);
    System.out.println("Promedio Notas Mobile : "+promedioNMobile);

    System.out.println("Cantidad de alumnos en Tec.Web : "+cantidadAlumWeb);

    System.out.println("Cantidad de alumnos en Tec.Mobile : "+cantidadAlumMobile);
```

Comment: Elimina esto: `promedioW++;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el pequeño error esta en

```
sumatoriaPW+=promedioW;
sumatoriaPM+=promedioM;
```

ya que cuando ingresas por ejemplo un "Web", y a la siguiente un "Mobile" el valor que tiene asignado "promedioW" nunca fue igualado a 0, por lo que vuelve a sumar el valor anterior, lo recomendable sería guardar cada uno en su respectivo "case:" o despues de realizar la suma, igualar a 0 ambos por ejemplo:

```
sumatoriaPW+=promedioW;
promedioW = 0;
sumatoriaPM+=promedioM;
promedioM = 0;
```

También tienes un

```
promedioM++;
promedioW++;
```

que se deben eliminar, y por ultimo, una pequeña recomendación, todos los promedios que se calculan o almacenan siempre deben ser en variables de tipo real (float, double) y el dentro del "for", deberías iniciar la condición en 0 o sumarle 1 a la cantidad de alumnos, te dejo el código:

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int alumnos = 4;
        int dni = 0;
        String carrera = " ";
        int parcial1W = 0;
        int parcial1M = 0;
        int parcial2W = 0;
        int parcial2M = 0;
        int notaTPW = 0;
        int notaTPM = 0;
        float promedioW = 0;
        float promedioM = 0;
        int cantidadAlumMobile = 0;
        int cantidadAlumWeb = 0;
        int promedioWeb = 0;
        int sumaW = 0;
        int sumaM = 0;
        float sumatoriaPW = 0;
        float sumatoriaPM = 0;
        float promedioNWeb = 0;
        float promedioNMobile = 0;

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 1; i < alumnos; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ".Ingrese DNI : ");
            dni = teclado.nextInt();
            System.out.println(i + ".Ingrese Carrera : ");
            carrera = teclado.next();
            switch (carrera) {
                case "Web":
                    System.out.println(i + ".Ingrese nota del 1er parcial : ");
                    parcial1W = teclado.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(i + "Ingrese nota del 2do parcial : ");
                    parcial2W = teclado.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(i + "Ingrese nota del T.P : ");
                    notaTPW = teclado.nextInt();
                    sumaW = parcial1W + parcial2W + notaTPW;
                    promedioW = sumaW / 3;
                    System.out.println(i + ".Promedio : " + promedioW);
                    cantidadAlumWeb++;
                    sumatoriaPW += promedioW;
                    break;
                case "Mobile":
                    System.out.println(i + ".Ingrese nota del 1er parcial : ");
                    parcial1M = teclado.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(i + "Ingrese nota del 2do parcial : ");
                    parcial2M = teclado.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(i + "Ingrese nota del T.P : ");
                    notaTPM = teclado.nextInt();
                    sumaM = parcial1M + parcial2M + notaTPM;
                    promedioM = sumaM / 3;
                    System.out.println(i + ".Promedio : " + promedioM);
                    cantidadAlumMobile++;
                    sumatoriaPM += promedioM;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Error! Carrera Inexistente.");
                    break;
            }
        }

        promedioNWeb = sumatoriaPW / cantidadAlumWeb;
        promedioNMobile = sumatoriaPM / cantidadAlumMobile;

        System.out.println("Promedio Notas WEB : " + promedioNWeb);
        System.out.println("Promedio Notas Mobile : " + promedioNMobile);

        System.out.println("Cantidad de alumnos en Tec.Web : " + cantidadAlumWeb);
        System.out.println("Cantidad de alumnos en Tec.Mobile : " + cantidadAlumMobile);
    }
}
```

Saludos

Comment: Muchas Gracias , ya funciona :D ...Saludos!